# Can't access gitlab-ci environment variables in build.gradle UPD: when using kaniko

Tags: gradle, gitlab, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I want to get gitlab environment variable and use it in build.gradle script. I defined the variable in gitlab-ci:

```
 build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    TEST: "HELLO WORLD"
  script:
    - export
```

Also, I use -export command to print all variables. And I see my TEST variable in gitlab job console. But when I'm trying to get this variable in build.gradle it is null. Here is build.gradle code fragment:

```
    if (System.getenv('TEST') != null) {
    repositories {
        println 'CI=' + System.getenv('CI')
        println 'M- ' + System.getenv('MAVEN_REPO_USER')
        println 'T- ' + System.getenv('TEST')
        println 'CI_JOB_STAGE ' + System.getenv('CI_JOB_STAGE')
        mavenCentral()
    }
} else {
    repositories {
        println '*CI= ' + System.getenv('CI')
        println '*MAven ' + System.getenv('MAVEN_REPO_USER')
        println '* ' + System.getenv('CI_JOB_STAGE')
        println 'T-+++ ' + System.getenv('TEST')
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

All environment variables printed as null's, but I see all of these in gitlab job console printed by -export command, before gradle trying to print them. What is wrong?

UPDATE: In ci-gitlab I'm using kaniko : - /kaniko/executor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get variable it must be defined with ARG instruction in Dockerfile and in gitlab-ci as build-arg. The ARG instruction sets the variables that the user passes to the image collector.

Dockerfile:

```
ARG TEST
```

gitlab-ci:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - /kaniko/executor
      --build-arg TEST="HELLO WORLD"
```

'variables: ' section is not neccessary